# numpy: elision versus in-place

Tags: python, numpy, performance

I'm aware of the [elision that numpy can do](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.13.0-notes.html), but in the following situation I'd expect that (at best) neither approach has to allocate any new storage and hence they'd perform at the same speed:

```py
import numpy as np
import cProfile

# generate random input for the 'blue' channel of an image
im_shape = (900, 1600, 3)
foo_B_chan = np.random.randint(low=0, high=256, size=im_shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)
# pre-allocated buffer for output
y_buf = np.ndarray(im_shape, dtype=np.uint8)
# the 'blue' channel alone
y_buf_B_chan = y_buf[:,:,2]

def elided_then_copyto(x_B_chan, y_B_chan):
    z = x_B_chan + 1
    np.copyto(y_B_chan, z)

def copyto_then_incr(x_B_chan, y_B_chan):
    np.copyto(y_B_chan, x_B_chan)
    y_B_chan += 1

with cProfile.Profile() as pr:
    for j in np.arange(1000):
        elided_then_copyto(foo_B_chan, y_buf_B_chan)
        copyto_then_incr(foo_B_chan, y_buf_B_chan)
    pr.print_stats(sort=2)
```

However, the `elided_then_copyto` takes about 60% of the time that `copy_then_inplace` uses.

The bytecode of the elided-then-copy method looks about what I'd expect:

```
# dis.dis(elided_then_copyto)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x_B_chan)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              4 BINARY_ADD
              6 STORE_FAST               2 (z)

  3           8 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (np)
             10 LOAD_METHOD              1 (copyto)
             12 LOAD_FAST                1 (y_B_chan)
             14 LOAD_FAST                2 (z)
             16 CALL_METHOD              2
             18 POP_TOP
             20 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

As does the copy-then-inplace:

```
# dis.dis(copyto_then_inplace)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (np)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              1 (copyto)
              4 LOAD_FAST                1 (y_B_chan)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (x_B_chan)
              8 CALL_METHOD              2
             10 POP_TOP

  3          12 LOAD_FAST                1 (y_B_chan)
             14 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             16 INPLACE_ADD
             18 STORE_FAST               1 (y_B_chan)
             20 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

Does anyone know what the extra overhead of the in-place operation is?

When I looked at the code via `pprof`, the main difference appears to be a much *much* slower application of the addition (better vectorisation and maybe cache-hit benefits in the elided case), but even the array copies are slower.

Here's the 'elided' output in pprof

[image: pprof snippet for elided - add_AVX2=233ms]

Versus the 'in place' (+=) pprof output:

[image: pprof snippet for 'in-place' - add_AVX2=1996ms]

Comment: `+=` is not in place, it is buffered.  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.htmlv

Comment: @hpaulj - not sure I understand: why is `numpy.add.to(y_B_buf, None, 1)` about 100 times slower?